# I want keep this Stopwatch screen running while switching through screens

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter, flutter-cupertino

I have this Flutter iOS styled Stopwatch and I would like to keep the stopwatch running while I switch through screens.

[Actual Stopwatch behavior](https://youtu.be/6Tw9VPpgpj8)

I already tried with some setState positioned inside the initState function of my Stopwatch but this didn't work.

I think that it doesn't rebuild the widget when I come back to the Stopwatch screen.

//My builder inside a home_screen.dart file

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      controller: controller,
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Ionicons.getIconData('ios-globe'),
            ),
            title: Text('World Clock'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Ionicons.getIconData('ios-alarm'),
            ),
            title: Text('Alarm'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Ionicons.getIconData('ios-bed'),
            ),
            title: Text('Bedtime'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Ionicons.getIconData('ios-stopwatch'),
            ),
            title: Text('Stopwatch'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Ionicons.getIconData('ios-timer'),
            ),
            title: Text('Timer'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, i) {
        if(i == 3){
          final Dependencies dependencies = new Dependencies();
          return StopWatch(dependencies: dependencies,);
        }else{
          return CupertinoTabView(
            builder: (context){
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                  middle: Text(chooseMiddle(i)),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Screen $i'),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you switch between tabs it causes to rebuild the screen and hence creating a new object of the StopWatch widget in the tab builder.  You will have to user PageStorageBucket and PageStorageKeys to maintain the pages.

Something like this should help

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeWidget();
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends State<HomeScreen>{

final List<Widget> pages = [
    DashboardScreen(
      key: PageStorageKey('Dashboard'),
    ),
    CarsScreen(
      key: PageStorageKey('Cars'),
    ),
    MapScreen(
      key: PageStorageKey('Find'),
    ),
    ProfileScreen(
      key: PageStorageKey('Profile'),
    ),
    SettingScreen(
      key: PageStorageKey('Settings'),
    )
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
  currentIndex: selectedIndex,
  items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home), title: Text('Home')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.car), title: Text('My Cars')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.search), title: Text('Find')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.profile_circled), title: Text('Profile')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.settings), title: Text('Settings')),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Smart Park'),
        ),
        body: PageStorage(
          child: pages[_selectedIndex],
          bucket: bucket,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),   
      );
  }
}
```